# Raising exceptions in Deferred callbacks

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def callback1(result):
  print "callback1 called with ",result
  return result

def callback2(result):
  print "callback2 called with ",result

def callback3(result):
  raise Exception("callback 3")

def errback(result):
  print 'handled error'
  return 'everything fine now'

d = Deferred()
d.addCallback(callback1)
d.addCallback(callback2)
d.addCallbacks(callback3, errback)
d.callback("Test")
```

I expect the output to be :

```
callback1 called with Test
callback2 called with Test
Unhandled Error
....
```

But what i actually get is

```
callback1 called with Test
callback2 called with Test
```

Since exceptions raised at level N in the callback chain are handled by the errback at level N+1, and there is no error handler added after adding callback3, i expect 'Unhandled exception...' to be thrown, but that is not happening . Am i missing something here ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your example, I see the output you expect:

```
callback1 called with  Test
callback2 called with  Test
Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 21, in <module>
    d.callback("Test")
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 393, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 501, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "t.py", line 11, in callback3
    raise Exception("callback 3")
exceptions.Exception: callback 3
```

with multiple versions of Twisted.  Did you actually run that exact script as-is?  I would assume you re-typed the output, and did not copy and paste it, since you only had one space between `with` and `Test` rather than two which is what is actually printed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glyph.  You are right, the example does give the expected output when run as a python script. I was running it from the Python REPL. Why would it not throw the Unhandled Error in the REPL ?

Comment: The unhandled error is printed when the `Deferred` is garbage collected while it is still in a failing state.  If you exit the interpreter with control-D (or control-Z enter, on Windows) you will see it printed.  The problem is that while you still have a reference to `d`, you might still add an errback which will handle the error, so you might recover.